# Why don't we seed vectors with $0$ values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Two vectors of different lengths cannot be added, or multiplied, and this carries over to matrices. An $n{\times}m$ matrix $A$ can only be multiplied by an  $m{\times}p$ matrix $B$.

Why don't we just seed the vector/matrix with $0$ values to give them the right length/dimension-length?

I don't know how to represent matrices in LaTeX (plus I'm using the Android app so it not really convenient for me to start looking it up for a he purposes of this question) or I would have provided examples.

## EDIT

Let's say we want to add a vector $u = [a_1, a_2, a_3, ...., a_n]$ and a vector $v = b_1, b_2, b_3, ..., b_{n+1}$, I am proposing we set $a_{n+1}$ to $0$, then add as desired.

Comment: Let's say we want to add a vector $u = [a_1, a_2, a_3, ...., a_n]$ and a vector $v = b_1, b_2, b_3, ..., b_{n+1}$, I am proposing we set $a_{n+1}$ to $0$, then add as desired.

Answer (score 4):

If we did that, we would lose properties like $A + B - A = B$, and the resulting set would no longer be a group. For example, taking $A=[0,0,0]$ and $B=[0,0]$ results in your case in $$A+B-A=[0,0,0]\neq[0,0]=B.$$

So, we would have to gain something pretty powerful to lose a whole heap of nicely behaving properties in exchange.

Comment: We cab just subtract or add the trailing zeros as desired though? I mean I can think of cases when it may be convenient to seed the matrix/vector with zero values so it's a desired length. E.g in solving linear equations. Upcoming anyway, since it's a valid answer.

Comment: @TobiAlafin Sure you *can* do that. But that means you have to **again** redefine the $+$ operator, and the resulting definition will be a whole lot of messy conditions, and the result will **STILL** not be a group because it will not have a unique identity element. It will all be orders of magnitude more complicated and ugly compared to how we do things now.

Answer (score 4):

To adress your edit:

If you consider only vectors and not matrices, there is a very common mathematical object where we already do that:
**polynomials**

These can be understood as infinite vectors where only finitely many entries are non-zero.
The addition of polynomials is a useful operation, even if they have different degree.
So a vector $[a_1, \dots, a_n]$ corresponds to a polynomial $a_1 + a_2 x + \dots + a_n x^{n-1}$,
and a vector $[b_1, \dots, b_{n+1}]$ corresponds to a polynomial $b_1 + b_2 x + \dots + b_{n+1} x^{n}$,
then the addition is exactly your desired result, which corresponds to expanding the first vector with a $0$ element.